# What is the longest time you can leave your computer doing a repetetive task without it taking damage?

Tags: desktop-computer, tasks

For example, let's say we have a game where you run a bike around a tower by pressing down W. You can keep pressing W down for eternity the game will just loop. For every step, you gain 1 point.
The computer always has power.

How long can you safely let the computer running before it can take damage in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Computers are good at repetitive tasks.

If they don't overheat in the first few minutes, they never will whilst doing that task.

I've had computers doing sets of the same repetitive tasks for 10 years; only rebooting for OS updates etc every month or three, the rest of the time working, 24/7/365.

Note: If you're going to leave a computer running constantly for years, you do have to strip & clean it 2 or 3 times a year, or the dust will eventually cause overheats. Other than that, if it's working within tolerance, it can just keep going...

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Are you _totally_ sure that they cannot _in any way_ get damaged?

Comment: Everything wears out eventually, but generally if they can do a task for an hour they can do it for a week... or a year…

Comment: Okay thank you very much! That was all I needed to know. I will mark your answer as correct.

Comment: @LauritsL.L. Computers were designed to be used.  I have allowed my PC to sit idle for weeks at a time.  There is no absolutes in life and electronics do fail, sometimes they fail after 3 weeks of being unplugged, and when they are turned on they simply don’t work.

Comment: Oh, btw, if you're going to leave a computer running constantly for years, you do have to strip & clean it 2 or 3 times a year, or the dust will eventually cause overheats. Other than that, if it's working within tolerance, it can just keep going...